# Cant login to admin page with OpenCart.

Tags: opencart

I just installed OpenCart for the 5th time and I always get stuck on the same page ..

I get no errors when I install it but when I try to login to the admin page i always get stuck.. It shows no errors if i try with correct username / password.

Do someone here had the same problem?

Please answer..

Comment: How did you install it? Softaculous or manually?

Answer (score 8):

Do you have any non-www to www rewrites in effect in a `.htaccess` file? This is one instance where I've seen this happen - where the admin is set to use `yourdomain.com/admin/` but your server is set to rewrite all non-www to `www.yourdomain.com`

If you open up your `admin/config.php` - find the url's for the `HTTP_SERVER` etc and change them all to `www.` if they're not already, and vice versa if they do have `www.`

Then save, and reload your admin page and try to log in. Hopefully it will then work

Comment: I dont realy understand this is in my config.

// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://aferm.nu/kalas/opencart/upload/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://aferm.nu/kalas/opencart/upload/');

Thanks

Comment: right, so change aferm.nu to www.aferm.nu in all of those, and see if it fixes it

Comment: i have got the same issue, and all my urls are with www, still it comes to same page after login

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks! Changed the config to reflect the forced www.

Comment: @JayGilford. why my admin not working? please give me solutions. below my website URL
https://www.jugglegear.com/juggledemos/admincontrol

Answer (score 0):

If the php.ini session cookie flag is set to secure and you are trying to access your site without ssl then this is the odd behaviour or issue you will encounter whenever you attempt to login.

This is a server setting found in the php.ini file.

```
session.cookie_secure = 1
```

set it to

```
session.cookie_secure = 0
```

IT is actually always a good idea to have secure enabled if you have an SSL cert on your server. Otherwise if not make sure it is disabled.

Comment: Amazing that this still fixes login issue in version 2.3.0.1

Answer (score -1):

Just found the answer here :

https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/729

after I modified /vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_session.php (removing "session_start(); " my problem apparently solved but I can't login to admin panel, so I get back and put the line back and problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

This usually happens because of sessions.In magneto if you comment out three lines in one folder and delete some session files restart server.Problem soloves.I am sure here also it is because of sessions.I will solove the problem and post it here.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are using 'db' option to save the session and for some reason I didn't know yet it's bugged. Try changing it to 'file' in both 'catalog.php' and 'config.php' inside 'system\config'

`$_['session_engine'] = 'file';`

Answer (score -3):

i just changed php versiyon from 7.4 to 7.1. Cause session is collapse with the other websites on the same server.